# Check if string of one table are all contained in another table

Tags: r

I have two tables T1 (3 columns) and T2 (2 columns)

T1:

```
Name  Age  Num
John  20   a, c, b
Lily  19   d, h, e
```

T2:

```
Item    Num
pen     a, c, q, b
pencil  d, z, h, e
apple   a, c, y
```

column Code are in string format.
I want to check if T1$Num all numbers are in the T2$Num and add corresponding T2$Item to T1.
The code is something like

```
 T1 <- sqldf("SELECT *, T2.Item FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 WHERE T1.Num are all contained in T2.Num")
```

I am supposed to get

```
Name  Age  Num         Item
John  20   a, c, b     pen
Lily  19   d, h, e     pencil
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add you data using `dput` function. Also, why on final data from line 1 `q` is gone and from line 2 `z` is gone?

Comment: Can you also say what should happen if a person's values match multiple items?

Comment: Num is used to do the matching and it's not added to the new table. Can assume T2 Num only has unique digit, so that no one (T1)  to multiple (T2) will occur. But multiple to one and one to one is allowed. Sorry I should have specified this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Using the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and assuming that the components of `Num` are in the same order in both `T1` and `T2` (which is the case with the data in the question -- we relax this assumption later on) we can use `replace` to convert `T1.Num` into a `like` pattern and then match that against `T2.Num` performing a left join.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select T1.*, T2.Item, T2.Num Num2 from T1 
       left join T2 on T2.Num like '%' || replace(T1.Num, ', ', '%') || '%'")
```

giving:

```
  Name Age     Num   Item       Num2
1 John  20 a, c, b    pen a, c, q, b
2 Lily  19 d, h, e pencil d, z, h, e
3 Jake  10    a, d   <NA>       <NA>
```

If it is not the case that the components of `Num` are ordered the same way in `T1` and `T2` then sort them first like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

T1x <- T1 %>%
  separate_rows(Num) %>%
  arrange(Name, Num) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarize(Num = toString(Num)) %>%
  ungroup

T2x <- T2 %>%
  separate_rows(Num) %>%
  arrange(Item, Num) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarize(Num = toString(Num)) %>%
  ungroup

sqldf("select T1x.*, T2x.Item, T2x.Num Num2 from T1x 
       left join T2x on T2x.Num like '%' || replace(T1x.Num, ', ', '%') || '%'")
```

**2)** This alternative uses dplyr and tidyr without sqldf.

```
T1Long <- T1 %>%
  separate_rows(Num)

T1Long %>%
  left_join(T1Long %>% count(Name), by = "Name") %>%
  left_join(T2 %>% separate_rows(Num), by = "Num") %>%
  group_by(Name, Item, n) %>%
  summarize(Num = toString(Num), Count = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(Count == n) %>%
  select(-Count, -n)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Name  Item   Num    
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  
1 John  pen    a, c, b
2 Lily  pencil d, h, e
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines1 <- "
Name  Age  Num
John  20   a, c, b
Lily  19   d, h, e
Jake  10   a, d"

Lines2 <- "
Item    Num
pen     a, c, q, b
pencil  d, z, h, e
apple   a, c, y"

T1 <- read.table(text = gsub("  +", ";", trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines1)))), 
  header = TRUE, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE)
T2 <- read.table(text = gsub("  +", ";", trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines2)))), 
  header = TRUE, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: If I add one more row to T1: (Jake   20    a, d), which does not match any column in T2. How should I write the query if I want to show this row as (Jake  20  a,b  NA  NA)? The 2 NA are Item and Num2 respectively. Is this possible to combine the two query into one? Thank you